# printing an element of a char array in c

Tags: c, arrays, string

here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int x,y,i,j,k;
char c;
char n_avion[6][20]={'BOING747','AIRBUSA380','LEARJET45','DC10','ANTONOV32','CONCORDE'};
char c_avion[6][2]={'B0','AB','Lj','DC','AN','CO'};
int  v_avion[6]={800,950,700,900,560,1400};
int  r_avion[]={10000,12000,4500,8000,2500,16000};

printf("\nEntrer LE Code d'Avion s'il vous plait : ");

    for(i=0; i<6 ;i++){
    printf("%c", n_avion[i]);
    }
```

when I try to printout n_avion using `%c` it gives me this `päÿ¼└È`

And when I try to printout n_avion using `%s` it gives me this `70502E`

what I really want is this `BOING747`

Plz any help and Thanks

Comment: `'` is for character literals, not string literals.

Comment: C uses double quotes (`"`) for strings.  Change `'BOING747'`, etc.  to `"BOEING747"` (sorry, being pedantic about spelling here).

Comment: Change `%c` to `%s` to print a string.  And use double quotes for your string constants.

Comment: @JohnBode for a good reason in this case, who wants to fly in a "boing" ... :o

Comment: @FelixPalmen -- perhaps in a "Böing" ;)

Comment: It looks like you forgot `-Wall -Wextra` or equivalent - otherwise your compiler warnings would have helped you fix the code.  Compiling without warnings is really not recommended.

Comment: `c_avion[6][2]` --> `c_avion[6][3]` to make room for the string termination

Comment: If it 'aint Boing, I 'aint goeing.

Answer (score 3):

There are many issues:

- strings must be included between `"` and not between `'`
- `c_avion[6][2]` should be `c_avion[6][3]` you need one more char for the string terminator (strings are terminated by a NUL character)
- `printf("%c", n_avion[i])` is using the wrong format specifier for strings, it should be `%s`  instead of `%c`
- put a `\n` at the end of the printf format string, otherwise the names will be printed on a single line without spaces (try)

Corrected code:

```
int main()
{
  int x, y, i, j, k;
  char c;
  char n_avion[6][20] = { "BOING747","AIRBUSA380","LEARJET45","DC10","ANTONOV32","CONCORDE" };
  char c_avion[6][3] = { "B0","AB","Lj","DC","AN","CO" };
  int  v_avion[6] = { 800,950,700,900,560,1400 };
  int  r_avion[] = { 10000,12000,4500,8000,2500,16000 };

  printf("\nEntrer LE Code d'Avion s'il vous plait : ");

  for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", n_avion[i]);
  }
}
```

BTW: my crystall ball tells be you will need to use `struct`s sooner or later.

**Other hint**:

Don't use "magic numbers" like `6` or `3` but use constants.

For example:

```
#define NAMELENGTH 20
#define SHORTNAMELENGTH 3
#define NBOFPLANES 6
...
char n_avion[NBOFPLANES][NAMELENGTH] = ...
char c_avion[NBOFPLANES][SHORTNAMELENGTH] = ...
...
etc.
```

Comment: `6` and `3` are constants, so it is not helpful to tell somebody learning the language to use constants rather than using `6` and `3`. It is like saying “Do not eat apples and bananas; eat fruit.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil right, made that clear in the answer

Answer (score 2):

C differentiates 'x' as a character and "x" as a string ('x' and a NULL character).  You want to print the strings, so use "%s" after setting your strings.

Comment: Woow guys Thank you very match it worked 

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to declare something like this

```
char n_avion[6][20]={'BOING747','AIRBUSA380','LEARJET45','DC10','ANTONOV32','CONCORDE'};
char c_avion[6][2]={'B0','AB','Lj','DC','AN','CO'};
```

I hope the intention is to define array of strings, in which case values needs to be in double quotes.

```
char n_avion[6][20]={"BOING747","AIRBUSA380","LEARJET45","DC10","ANTONOV32","CONCORDE"};
char c_avion[6][2]={"B0","AB","Lj","DC","AN","CO"};
```

having said that a string is a character array terminated with `'\0'` character

however here, there is no space for '\0' character at all because the size is restricted to 2 as defined in `char c_avion[6][2]`, so make some room for `'\0'`

```
char c_avion[6][3]={"B0","AB","Lj","DC","AN","CO"};
```

finally the printf

simply put `"%s"`  is for strings and `"%c"` for characters